# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/a_n)^n=\lim e^{n/a_n}$, where $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

We know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/n)^n = e$  
The following that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/a_n)^n=\lim e^{n/a_n}$, 
where $a_n$ is positive sequence and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n}=\infty$
is true?

Comment: More generally, $$\lim A_n^{B_n} = (\lim A_n)^{\lim B_n}$$ unless it is one of the usual indeterminate forms like $0^0$ or $1^\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for asking my questions.~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is true. ***Hint:*** You can show that
$\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ f(x)}=1$ and $\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ g(x)}=+\infty$
implies that
$$\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ f(x)^{g(x)}}=e^{\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ 
\left(f(x)-1\right)g(x)}}$$
whenever $\underset{x\to a}{\lim}{\ 
\left(f(x)-1\right)g(x)}$ exists.

To see this you can Write the following:
$$f(x)^{g(x)}=\left(\left(1+(f(x)-1)\right)^{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}}\right)^{(f(x)-1)g(x)}$$
then you can use the assertion of **GEdgar's** comment. You have to recall that

$$\underset{u\to 0}{\lim}{\ (1+u)^{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{u}}}} = e $$

and, so we get

$$ \underset{x\to a }{\lim}{\ \bigg(1+(f(x)-1)\bigg)^{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}}}
= \underset{u\to 0}{\lim}{\ (1+u)^{\displaystyle{\frac{1}{u}}}}=e
 $$
using the change of variables $u=f(x)-1$. Then, $u\to 0$ as $x\to a$.

Comment: Thank you for asking my questions. I'll dive into your answer~!!